# Get Error When Compile Source (.C) file Using Microsoft Visual C/C++ compiler via GnuWin32 in Windows 7

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, compiler-construction, gnu-make

I will show you step as below ....

First You Download [GNUWIN32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm).

Then Install on windows 7 and Set Environment Path.

1. I will make **a.C** Source file shown as below

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   int main()
   {
       //FileName: a.C
       printf("Hello World !!! Its works");
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. I will to make **Makefile**. shown as below

   ```
   #MakeFile Source Code... FileName: Makefile
   OBJS: a

   #add path visual c/c++ compiler
   PATH=C:/Program Files\ (x86)\Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\ 9.0/VC

   CC: $(PATH)/bin/cl.exe

   all: a

   a: 
       $(CC) -c a.C

   clean:
       rm -rf $(OBJS)
   ```
3. I compile Source code. it get error.

   ```
   Input: C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Test>make

   output:
   cc -c a.C
   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc -c a.C, ...) failed.
   make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
   make: *** [a] Error 2
   ```

Please Let Me help, How to build this code using visual c++ compiler.

Comment: why do you need to overcomplicate with GnuWin32 when you clearly have a Visual Studio installed?

Comment: You need to use the vsvars.bat file that comes with Visual Studio to set up the command line environment.

Comment: Hello, fritzone thanks for your replay. i build sqlcrypt source file with latest sqlite version but that follows this procedure...

Comment: Hello, Paul R Thanks for your replay but that procedure already follows.

Answer (score 1):

`PATH` is the wrong name to use for a variable in your Makefile, because it is also the name of the variable that lists the paths to be searched when looking for other programs.  Change it to something else.

Comment: Hello Tom Thanks for your replay. Path Name was change and recompile again it get same error

Answer (score 1):

There's a semantic error in your makefile. You are defining CC as a target, not a variable. Fix it thus:

```
CC=$(PATH)/bin/cl.exe
```

The clue is in the error message `process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc -c a.C, ...) failed.`. You can see that it's trying to execute `cc` not `cl.exe`

Comment: Hello andy brown thanks for replay but i will change from CC to cc but it get same error. but you give me example build a.C file using Visual C++ compiler via Make command.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at `vcvars32.bat`, provided by μSoft to set up your environment for the compiler, you will see that it adds *several* folders to your `%PATH%` environment variable.

You can express this `%PATH%` minging in *make* if you want to. Something like

```
export PATH := /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/Common7/IDE:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/BIN:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/Common7/Tools:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/VCPackages:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v6.0A/bin:${PATH}:/cygdrive/C/PROGRA~1/MICROS~2.0/VC/redist/DEBUG_~1/x86/MICROS~1.DEB
```

Yes, this is *make* syntax. It augments any existing `%PATH%` with a prefix and a suffix (see that `${PATH}` right in the middle?).

Note though that this is in a format ready for cygwin *make*. You may need a few adjustments. Oh, and don't forget that `cl.exe` needs decent settings for `%INCLUDE%`, `%LIB%` and `%LIBPATH%` too.